# Why is my to_base_n Program not working?

Tags: c, radix

I need to write a C program which will read a number (in base 10) from user input and output it in any base which is a power of 2. The calculations have to be performed in one function, `to_base_n`, which takes the parameters `num` and `base` and prints the number in the respective base. As a validation check, the program also checks if the base is a power of two with the `isPowerofTwo` function.

The way the conversion is carried out is by means of long division which carries out the logic in the pseudocode below:

```
void to_base_n(int x, int n){
    int r, i = 0
    int digits[16]
    while (x ≠ 0){
        r = x mod n
        x = x / n
        digits[i] = r 
        i++
    }
    for (i = 0, i < 15, i++)
         print digits[i]
}
```

Which I believe is arithmetically sound. But when  I try to, for example, convert 82000 to base 4, I get the following output:

[image: Output]

The large digits appearing are even bigger than `num` itself, so I figured the modulus cannot be entering the array properly (because ∀{x,n}; x mod n < x). I can't seem to find what's wrong with it. The full code is listed below.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isPowerofTwo(int);
void to_base_n(int, int);

int main(){

    //Variables
    int num, base;

    //Prompt
    printf("Please enter a number in base 10: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("Please enter a base (2^n) to convert it to: ");
    scanf("%d", &base);

    //Precaution
    while(!isPowerofTwo(base)){
        printf("That number is not a power of 2. Please try again: ");;
        scanf("%d", &base);
    }

    if(isPowerofTwo(base)){
    //Output
    printf("The number %d (base 10) is equivalent to ", num);
    to_base_n(num, base);
    printf(" (base %d).", base);
    }

    //Return Statement
    return 0;
}

//Checks if Base is a Power of Two
bool isPowerofTwo(int base){
    while((base % 2 == 0) && base > 1){
            base = base / 2;
            if(base == 1){
                return true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
}

//to_base_n
void to_base_n(int x, int n){
    int r, i = 0;
    int digits[16];
    while(x != 0){
        r = x % n;
        x = x / n;
        digits[i] = r;
        i++;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        printf("%d|",digits[i]);
}
```

Can anyone help explain what's wrong with it?

Comment: It's a good practice to check bounds for an array you write to (i < 16)

Comment: This does not even compile.

Comment: @Olaf you need a psuedo code compiler.

Comment: @Olaf The C program itself should work fine, unless you tried compiling the pseudocode.

Comment: @LukeCollins: Sorry, I overlooked that in the text. However, pseudocode normally is more compact, so I wonder why you actually posted that. Nevermind!

Comment: @Olaf Haha, I guess I'm so used to the syntax that it comes naturally to express things that way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number 82000 in base 4 would be:
110001100
Which is exacly what you get. Your mistake is that:

- They are printed backwards.
- You are printing more digits than you should, so you print garbage.

Comment: Thank you! I thought it had something to do with garbage, I was going to do something like this to solve it though: `for(i=0; i<16, i++){ digits[i]=0}`

Answer (score 1):

You ignore the number of digits extracted with your pseudo code, so you print uninitialised elements of the array.

```
for (i = 0, i < 15, i++)
    print digits[i]
```

And they are printed in reverse order. I suggest changing it to this

```
for (i = i - 1, i >= 0, i--)
    print digits[i]
```

and as C code in your function

```
for(i = i - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    printf("%d|",digits[i]);
```